# Convert PCM wave data to numpy arrays and vice versa

Tags: numpy, audio, webrtc, pcm, librosa

**The situation**

I am using VAD (Voice Activity Detection) from WebRTC by using [WebRTC-VAD](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad), a Python adapter. The [example implementation](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/blob/master/example.py) from the GitHub repo uses Python's [wave module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/wave.html) to read PCM data from files. Note that according to the comments the module only works with mono audio and a sampling rate of either 8000, 16000 or 32000 Hz.

**What I want to do**

Read audio data from arbitrary audio files (MP3 and WAV files) with different sampling rates, convert them into the PCM-representation that WebRTC-VAD is using, apply WebRTC-VAD to detect voice activity and finally process the result by producing Numpy-Arrays again from PCM data because they are easiest to work with when using [Librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/)

**My problem**

The WebRTC-VAD module only works correctly when using the `wave` module. This module returns PCM data as `bytes` objects. It does not work when feeding it Numpy arrays that have been obtained e.g. by using `librosa.load(...)`. I have not found a way to convert between the two representations.

**What I have done so far**

I have written the following functions to read audio data from audio files and automatically convert them:

Generic function to read/convert any audio data with Librosa (--> returns Numpy array):

```
def read_audio(file_path, sample_rate=None, mono=False):       
    return librosa.load(file_path, sr=sample_rate, mono=mono)
```

Functions to read arbitrary data as PCM data (--> returns bytes):

```
def read_audio_vad(file_path):
    audio, rate = librosa.load(file_path, sr=16000, mono=True)
    tmp_file = 'tmp.wav'
    sf.write(tmp_file, audio, rate, subtype='PCM_16')
    audio, rate = read_pcm16_wave(tmp_file)
    remove(tmp_file)
    return audio, rate

def read_pcm16_wave(file_path):    
    with wave.open(file_path, 'rb') as wf:
        sample_rate = wf.getframerate()
        pcm_data = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
        return pcm_data, sample_rate
```

As you can see I am making a detour by reading/converting the audio data with librosa first. This is needed so I can read from MP3 files or WAV files with arbitrary encodings and automatically resample it to 16kHz mono with Librosa. I am then writing to a temporary file. Before deleting the file, I read the contents out again, but this time using the `wave` module. This gives me the PCM data.

I now have the following code to extract the voice activity and produce Numpy arrays:

```
def webrtc_voice(audio, rate):
    voiced_frames = webrtc_split(audio, rate)
    tmp_file = 'tmp.wav'
    for frames in voiced_frames:
        voice_audio = b''.join([f.bytes for f in frames])
        write_pcm16_wave(tmp_file, voice_audio, rate)
        voice_audio, rate = read_audio(tmp_file)
        remove(tmp_file)

        start_time = frames[0].timestamp
        end_time = (frames[-1].timestamp + frames[-1].duration)
        start_frame = int(round(start_time * rate / 1e3)) 
        end_frame = int(round(end_time * rate / 1e3)) 
        yield voice_audio, rate, start_frame, end_frame

def write_pcm16_wave(path, audio, sample_rate):
    with wave.open(path, 'wb') as wf:
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(2)
        wf.setframerate(sample_rate)
        wf.writeframes(audio)
```

As you can see I am taking the detour over a temporary file again to write PCM data first and then read the temporary file out again with Librosa to get a Numpy array. The `webrtc_split` function is the implementation from the [example implementation](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/blob/master/example.py) with only few minor changes. For completeness sake I am posting it here:

```
def webrtc_split(audio, rate, aggressiveness=3, frame_duration_ms=30, padding_duration_ms=300):
    vad = Vad(aggressiveness)

    num_padding_frames = int(padding_duration_ms / frame_duration_ms)
    ring_buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=num_padding_frames)
    triggered = False

    voiced_frames = []
    for frame in generate_frames(audio, rate):
        is_speech = vad.is_speech(frame.bytes, rate)

        if not triggered:
            ring_buffer.append((frame, is_speech))
            num_voiced = len([f for f, speech in ring_buffer if speech])
            if num_voiced > 0.9 * ring_buffer.maxlen:
                triggered = True
                for f, s in ring_buffer:
                    voiced_frames.append(f)
                ring_buffer.clear()
        else:
            voiced_frames.append(frame)
            ring_buffer.append((frame, is_speech))
            num_unvoiced = len([f for f, speech in ring_buffer if not speech])
            if num_unvoiced > 0.9 * ring_buffer.maxlen:
                triggered = False
                yield voiced_frames
                ring_buffer.clear()
                voiced_frames = []
    if voiced_frames:
        yield voiced_frames


class Frame(object):
    """
    object holding the audio signal of a fixed time interval (30ms) inside a long audio signal
    """

    def __init__(self, bytes, timestamp, duration):
        self.bytes = bytes
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.duration = duration


def generate_frames(audio, sample_rate, frame_duration_ms=30):
    frame_length = int(sample_rate * frame_duration_ms / 1000) * 2
    offset = 0
    timestamp = 0.0
    duration = (float(frame_length) / sample_rate)
    while offset + frame_length < len(audio):
        yield Frame(audio[offset:offset + frame_length], timestamp, duration)
        timestamp += duration
        offset += frame_length
```

**My question**

My implementation with writing/reading temporary files with the `wave` module and reading/writing these files with Librosa to get Numpy Arrays seems overly complicated to me. However, despite spending a whole day on the matter I did not find a way to convert directly between the two encodings. I admit I don't fully understand all the details of PCM and WAVE files, the impact of using 16/24/32-Bit for PCM data or the endianness. I hope my explanations above are detailed enough and not too much. Is there an easier way to convert between the two representations in-memory?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that WebRTC-VAD, and the Python wrapper, [py-webrtcvad](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad), expects the audio data to be 16bit PCM little-endian - as is the most common storage format in WAV files.

`librosa` and its underlying I/O library `pysoundfile` however always returns floating point arrays in the range `[-1.0, 1.0]`. To convertt this to bytes containing 16bit PCM you can use the following `float_to_pcm16` function.

```
def float_to_pcm16(audio):
    import numpy

    ints = (audio * 32767).astype(numpy.int16)
    little_endian = ints.astype('<u2')
    buf = little_endian.tostring()
    return buf


def read_pcm16(path):
    import soundfile

    audio, sample_rate = soundfile.read(path)
    assert sample_rate in (8000, 16000, 32000, 48000)
    pcm_data = float_to_pcm16(audio)
    return pcm_data, sample_rate
```

Comment: ndarray.tostring() is deprecated, use tobytes() instead

Comment: It should be "(audio * 32768)", not "(audio * 32767)"