# Voice Activity Detection

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, audio, speech-recognition, librosa

I am getting a problem while trying to get the binary result using webrctvad in a wave format audio file. I am using librosa in order to load the audio file in .wav format. Can anyone tell me how to use librosa along with webrtcvad in order to get the binary output of whether the audio contains speech or not?

[Webrtcvad module works correctly with the wave module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486093/convert-pcm-wave-data-to-numpy-arrays-and-vice-versa)

The above link helped me a lot but still, I am confused as the link contains a good explanation but during implementation lot of errors are coming.

Comment: What does your code look like so far, and what are the errors that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[py-webrtcvad](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad), expects the audio data to be 16bit PCM little-endian - as is the most common storage format in WAV files.

`librosa` and its underlying I/O library `pysoundfile` however always returns floating point arrays in the range `[-1.0, 1.0]`. To convertt this to bytes containing 16bit PCM you can use the following `float_to_pcm16` function.

And I have tested to use the `read_pcm16` function a direct replacement of `read_wave` in the official [py-webrtcvad example](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/blob/master/example.py). But allowing to open any audio file supported by soundfile (WAV, FLAC, OGG) etc.

```
def float_to_pcm16(audio):
    import numpy

    ints = (audio * 32767).astype(numpy.int16)
    little_endian = ints.astype('<u2')
    buf = little_endian.tostring()
    return buf


def read_pcm16(path):
    import soundfile

    audio, sample_rate = soundfile.read(path)
    assert sample_rate in (8000, 16000, 32000, 48000)
    pcm_data = float_to_pcm16(audio)
    return pcm_data, sample_rate
```